# Access Service Provider Context in HystrixCommand's RunFallbackAsync

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, hystrix, circuit-breaker, steeltoe

I am working to add the Hystrix CircuitBreaker pattern to an existing ASP.NET Core microservice, using Steeltoe [CircuitBreaker](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/steeltoe/tree/master/src/CircuitBreaker), while maintaining the existing logging functionality with minimal refactoring (or as little as I can hope for).

Currently, an incoming HTTP request goes through the following layers:

`Controller -> Service -> DerivedProvider -> AbstractProvider (and out to downstream service)`

with Hystrix, I would like it to be:

`Controller -> Service -> HystrixCommand<> -> DerviedProvider (via HystrixCommand's ExecuteAsync) -> AbstractProvider`

Lots of context is stored in the providers, which is passed down through the layers via constructors, and logging is then happening in the `AbstractProvider` using that context, regardless of the outgoing call's result. The `AbstractProvider` also supports a fair amount of custom logic, such as optional pre and post execution callbacks. The post callback is invoked when a non-success response message is returned. Needless to say, changing the layers drastically doesn't appear easy to me, with my current understanding.

After reviewing the [Hystrix documentation](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration) and [Steeltoe CircuitBreaker documentation](https://steeltoe.io/docs/steeltoe-circuitbreaker/) I am unclear if I can maintain, and access, the provider and its context within the `HystrixCommand<>.RunFallbackAsync()`.

Perhaps the answer might relate to the lifecycle hooks you can override? Like `onFallbackStart(HystrixInvokable commandInstance`?

Ultimately, the goal is simply to make sure that any existing callback/logging functionality is not lost by wrapping these existing `providers` in a `HystrixCommand`. I am failing to understand how the `HystrixCommand` manages the providers and its context, and when/where you do or do not have access to them. Any suggestions or direction you can offer would be very much appreciated! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Hystrix commands can be added to the service container or can be "new'd" (i.e. new MyHystrixCommand(...) whichever makes the most sense for you situation.

Remember that Hystrix commands can not be reused .. i.e. once you create and execute the command you must not try and reuse it.

Clearly if you are new'ng the HystrixCommand then you can define whatever arguments you want in the constructor and supply it with the right arguments (i.e. state) it needs to execute.

If you are injecting it into a controller or another service.. then before you use it... you can initialize it with whatever state you want using properties and then execute it.